# with a plugin for jquery google maps, how to capture coordinates of a point marked to save in the database?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-plugins, jquery-gmap3

Good morning,

I've been searching a google maps plugin for jquery, eg gMap3.
  But I am not able to capture the coordinates of a point marked on the map later.
  Anyone done this? know how to do? Would pass an example link if know any?

I appreciate the answers

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at mapstraciotn: http://mapstraction.com/

This library provides some useful APIs, and also abstracts out map providers, might be of use ...